# Italicizing scientific names in a legend

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, legend

I am trying to Italicize a scientific name in my legend (ArcMap 10.2). I can not figure out how to Italicize one word only without having the rest of the description being italicized as well. Is it possible to italicize only one word in a legend description?

Comment: This ArcMap help page may be what you need: [Adding mixed-format text to legend descriptions](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s80000000q000000.htm)

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is, but there's a bit of work to it.

The article in the previous answer related to *text description* fields which can be edited and entered manually for each symbol class:
[image: Description added]

These are automatically italic and their font can be changed without affecting the layer name or symbol classes.

If you want to italicize only *one* word in a symbol class you can use [formatting tags](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_text_formatting_tags/00s80000000p000000/):
[image: Layer name format tags]

In this example I changed the layer name to `Features <ITA><BOL>Using Formatting Tags</BOL></ITA>` and you can easily change just one word:
[image: format tags back to normal]

This time the layer name is `Features <ITA><BOL>(Format)</BOL></ITA> Back to normal`.

For multiple classes you can still use formatting tags:
[image: Classes symbology tab]

Change the label in the symbology tab. The value is not editable but the label is, this generates a legend that looks like this:

[image: Classes symbology legend]

Comment: Ta @ChrisW, fat fingers on a Friday morning!